# Kivy - rectangle binds to image with delay

Tags: python, kivy, bind

I want a rectangle to stick to the bottom left corner of an image. It works, but when I change window size the rectangle is little bit off. It is where image was before update. Here's the code:

```
from kivy.app import App, Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color


Builder.load_string(
'''
<Screen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: im
            keep_data: True
            source: 'test.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            size_hint_y: 0.9
            pos_hint: {'left':1, 'top':1}
        Button:
            text: 'Button'
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}
''')


class Screen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs) 
        with self.ids.im.canvas.after:
            Color(1,0,1,.5) 
            self.rec = Rectangle(pos=(self.ids.im.center_x - self.ids.im.norm_image_size[0] / 2,
                                      self.ids.im.center_y - self.ids.im.norm_image_size[1] / 2),
                                 size=(self.ids.im.norm_image_size[0]/2,
                                       self.ids.im.norm_image_size[1]/2))
        self.bind(pos=self.update_canvas, size=self.update_canvas)

    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        self.rec.pos = (self.ids.im.center_x - self.ids.im.norm_image_size[0] / 2,
                        self.ids.im.center_y - self.ids.im.norm_image_size[1] / 2)
        self.rec.size = (self.ids.im.norm_image_size[0]/2,
                         self.ids.im.norm_image_size[1]/2)


class QuestionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QuestionApp().run()
```

I'm doing this in Python because I want to randomly spawn rectangles within the image, but I'm stuck here with rectangles when window resizing being wobbly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the rectangle to use the geometry of the image as reference then you must do the binding with the image, for this change:

```py
self.bind(pos=self.update_canvas, size=self.update_canvas)
```

to

```py
self.ids.im.bind(pos=self.update_canvas, size=self.update_canvas)
```